# hash 160 (RIPEMD160) to public key

Tags: c++, c, bitcoin

is it possible to generate public key using hash 160 (RIPEMD160)..? i remember reading that with version 0 there is a way to calculate public key from the public key hash (RIPEMD160), if yes how can that be possible are there codes available for this ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to restore public key from RIPEMD160 hash. That would violate property of cryptographic hash function: you cannot restore original data from hash faster than brute-forcing.

You may have read about raw public keys stored in bitcoin blockchain. At the very beginning there was address type "Pay to Public Key". These addresses look the same as "Pay to Public Key Hash". They all start with "1". But redeem script actually has raw public key, and not `RIPEMD160(SHA256(public_key))` as in the case with "Pay to Public Key Hash".

Example. Coinbase transaction in block #124: [611b40973fe68cc42b70ae5af365a449af458d76086415c6fa6c45364c36278e](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/611b40973fe68cc42b70ae5af365a449af458d76086415c6fa6c45364c36278e)

Address: `1M7U7kbW9CY7znW6sSRzycgPCxr5LkJy2r`

Redeem script:

```
041fd091cdf05a34ffa28103adf83f399437d5bcf79fa07f55fe98f65a43a82e0ce5adbe6a3abb597d39573693453d8c1fac40ffb2ff2c9d9405940964d7cd6134 OP_CHECKSIG
```

65 bytes hex string is actually EC public key in uncompressed format.